# Convert and iterate through Javascript object array to PHP array

Tags: php, json, laravel-7

I have the following being sent to a PHP/Laravel endpoint which I am working on. I need to convert it to PHP array so I can iterate through the members but I can't seem to be able to do json_decode() on it

```
{
  levels: [
  {role_id:1, access_level_id:3}, 
  {role_id:2, access_level_id:1}, 
  {role_id:3, access_level_id:2}], 
  category_id: 3
}
```

On my backend I have my method as follows

```
 public function myfunctionname (Request $request)
{
  $levels = json_decode($request->levels);
}
```

I want to be able to iterate through the items in $request levels as a PHP array but $levels is returning as empty

I guess I am doing something wrong about this.

Please guide if you can
Thank you

Comment: whats `var_dump($request->levels)` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Read this solution only if you are using javascript to generate the json:*

When sending json via ajax you can turn it into a regular json string with JSON.stringify:

```
var v = {
  levels: [
  {role_id:1, access_level_id:3}, 
  {role_id:2, access_level_id:1}, 
  {role_id:3, access_level_id:2}], 
  category_id: 3
};
var j = JSON.stringify(v);
console.log(j);
```

```
{"levels":[{"role_id":1,"access_level_id":3},{"role_id":2,"access_level_id":1},{"role_id":3,"access_level_id":2}],"category_id":3}
```

... and you can decode this with json_decode(..., true) on PHP.

Comment: I was not using javascript to generate the json but I was getting it from a request to an endpoint at the backend I;m working on. However, getting the frontend developer to quote the keys properly fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are not quoted properly, this is the format that json_decode expects, this is the reason why you are getting null. To iterate through the items it's better to use json_decode($jsonString, true); Note the second parameter set as true, this second parameter will return an array instead of an object of type \stdClass.

See the following example:

https://3v4l.org/GM5fR